# How to bind IP Address:Port No with some domain name on wamp server

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp, hosting, wampserver

I need to bind the `IP:Port` to domain name globally.

**Example:**

> 123.123.123.321:8087

should be bound with

> stag.abc.com

My site is in wordpress on wamp server.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if this is what you need but ..

DNS only handles domain -> IP mapping. It cannot map the default port (80) to a custom port–you will have to use a reverse proxy for that. nginx is one of the most popular reverse proxies that are used to do that.

First, add a DNS record for your subdomain.

Then, install nginx:

How To Install Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Add a new server block:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name myapp.domain.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

}

Finally, enable it and restart nginx:
`sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp
sudo service nginx configtest
sudo service nginx restart`

You should now be able to browse to http://myapp.domain.com and see the contents of http://your droplet's ip:8080.

Comment: I am using windows server.

Comment: yeah but you can find a similar logic ...i will see if i can provide you sth about it..